# Вопрос о модификациях метода Эйлера

Tags: математика, численные-методы

Доброго времени суток! Помогите пожалуйста с ответом на один вопрос. Уверен тут есть люди знающие... Я надеюсь что вопрос не удалят, так как он не о программировании.

В общем суть вопроса: всем известно, что модификации метода Эйлера, а именно метод ломанных Эйлера и метод Эйлера-Коши для дифференциального уравнения находит искомую функцию лишь приближенно. Вопрос: возможно ли с помощью обоих этих методов найти точное решение для какой-либо функции. Если да, то для какой именно функции это можно сделать?
Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Например, для линейной функции метод Эйлера даст точное решение.

Comment: Да, с методом Эйлера я разобрался, он дает точное решение. 
У меня препод просит ответ конкретно для этих двух модификаций.

Comment: А что такое дифференциальное уравнение? Это уравнение с производными. Производная в свою очередь - это предел. Предел в общем виде можно вычислить только с заданной точностью. Для этого дифференциальные уравнения и предназначены. Какой практический смысл, например, вычислять длину окружности с бесконечной точностью?

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics для того чтобы проверять реализованный численный метод на аналитически известном решении.